# Passing values from Function to Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, function, ms-access, subroutine

I have been looking around for an answer to that, but have been unable to locate one that explains it well enough that I understand.

I have no experience with functions, and very little with VBA overall. So if I have a subroutine I am executing and then call a function that I pass parameters into, once that function runs how do I get the result back into the main subroutine to be used?

This is for Access where I am pulling a number from one record set then passing that to a function to be used for an insert to create a new number. I then need that number passed back to the subroutine to be used.

Comment: You can pass the parameter `ByRef` or return the value directly by the function

Comment: Could you provide a small example? I am a visual person so seeing helps immensely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have two alternatives.

Run the code using `F8` key to see what happens and make sure to activate the [Locals Window](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/8020/debugger-locals-window) so you see how variables values change

---

1- Return the value directly from a function

Run the `DoSomethingReturnFromFunction` sub

```
' Return value from function
Public Sub DoSomethingReturnFromFunction()
    
    ' Define a parameter
    Dim myParameter As String
    myParameter = "SomeValue"
    
    ' Call a function and store its value into a variable
    Dim myResult As Long
    myResult = MyFunction(myParameter)
    
    ' Print the result variable
    Debug.Print myResult

End Sub

Private Function MyFunction(ByVal myParameter as String) As Long

    Dim result As Long

    Select Case myParameter
    Case "SomeValue"
        result = 1
    Case Else
        result = 2
    End Select
    
    ' Assign the result value to the function
    MyFunction = result

End Function
```

Result: `Debug.Print myResult` prints to the inmediate window the value returned from the function

---

2- Change variable value passed ByRef inside another function

Run the `DoSomethingReturnFromByRef` sub

```
' Change variable value passed ByRef inside another function
Public Sub DoSomethingReturnFromByRef()
    
    ' Call a function
    Dim myByRefParameter As Long
    MySub myByRefParameter
    
    ' Print the result
    Debug.Print myByRefParameter

End Sub

Private Sub MySub(ByRef myByRefParameter As Long)
    
    ' Change the value of the variable passed ByRef inside the procedure
    myByRefParameter = 1

End Sub
```

Result: `Debug.Print myByRefParameter` prints to the inmediate window the value that is stored in the `myByRefParameter` variable originally declared in the `DoSomethingReturnFromByRef` procedure

Let me know if it's clear

Comment: That detailed it perfectly. I think I understand it and will try it and see if I manage to do it correctly.